# Is there an alternative to UIApplication.didBecomeActiveNotification with #selector?

Tags: objective-c, swift, selector, notificationcenter

I need to perform a `segue` to a `modal` from my `tabbar controller`. This won't work since there's a starting `tab` that overrides the modal segue (I think. The modal won't show). And I can't perform the `segue` in the starting `tab` since different product `targets` have different starting `tabs` and it would be messy having the same code in multiple places.

Anyway, I solved it by using

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(applicationDidBecomeActive), name: UIApplication.didBecomeActiveNotification, object: nil)

@objc func applicationDidBecomeActive(notification: Notification) {
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "Segue", sender: nil)
}
```

It works great. But, I don't want to use this old `@objc` code. Isn't there a mode modern swifty way to do this? I'm fine using `UIApplication.didBecomeActiveNotification`, but I want to get away from using the `#selector` and `@objc`.

Comment: Have you tried to find the answer in the documentation? The "Adding and Removing Notification Observers" section of `NotificationCenter` and the "See Also" section of  `addObserver(_:selector:name:object:)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are targeting iOS 13+, you can use `Combine` to observe `NotificationCenter` notifications without having to use selectors. The `publisher(for:)` function of `NotificationCenter` can be used for this.

```
var subscriptions = Set<AnyCancellable>()
let notificationPublisher = NotificationCenter.default.publisher(for: UIApplication.didBecomeActiveNotification)
notificationPublisher.sink { _ in performSegue(withIdentifier: "Segue", sender: nil) }.store(in: &subscriptions)
```

Comment: Ah, nice, thanks. Any idea how to manage it for Rx :) ?

Comment: @JoakimSjöstedt `NotificationCenter.default.rx.notification(UIApplication.didBecomeActiveNotification)` seems to be the way with RxSwift

Comment: Nice going, it worked great! Thanks alot for your help @David and for taking the time :)